# Auto Increment in MS ACCESS Query

Tags: ms-access

Does anybody know how to create auto-increment in the query?
eg.
id
1
2
3
4
.
.
create auto-increment in the query, Not in the table?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no such thing as autoincrement in a query. Do you want a row count? If so, post your SQL.

Comment: Thanks. What i need is, just the number for each row in the query output.eg.Number '1' should appear with the separate column ID, infront of the first row of the query output and so on.

Comment: You need to post your sql and what you think you are going to do with a row number, because there is not a lot you can do.

Comment: There are two ways I know of.  First use direct T-SQL and the rank function.  Second is to create a VBA counter that increments as it is called and use that value in your query.